# Is it true that $A\in\{A\cup B\}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm studying topology, and I've encountered a set $$\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}} = \bigg\{\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i:B_i\in\mathcal{B}\bigg\},$$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology, and $I$ is an index set.

The text then proves that $\mathcal{T_{\mathcal{B}}}$ is a topology.
As part of the proof, the following is said;

"Let $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{T_{\mathcal{B}}} $ (...)".

This has me a bit confused, as I'm not sure I understand if the individual sets of the union are actually in $\mathcal{T_{\mathcal{B}}}$.

My thought process is as follows:

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets.

Obviously, $A\subset A$ and $A\subset A\cup B$. Further, $A\in \{A\}$. But is $A\in\{A\cup B\}$? I can't seem to find a clear answer.

As an example, let $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$, and $S=\{A\cup B\}$. Then $S=\{\{1,2\}\cup\{2,3\}\}=\{\{1,2,3\}\}$. From what I understand, this set contains one element, and that element is $\{1,2,3\}$.

If this is correct, then how is the statement from the text justified?

Comment: That textbook seems to have sloppy notation.

Comment: The answer in the question title: yes, if and only if $A\cup B = A$, i.e. if and only if $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: How do you choose $I$? Because if the union is taken over all possible $I$, then $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal T _{\mathcal B}$ as you may choose $I = \{1\}, \{2\}$ respectively.

Comment: Seems to be a sloppy notation, I am guessing that the text tried to mean that the set contains every possible union, rather than just a single "union of everything". I mean like, $S$ probably does not refer to $\{A\cup B\}$, more like $S = \{\emptyset,A,B,A \cup B\}$

Comment: @qrsngky It seems the most natural thing to assume. Otherwise it is not even clear how the set of indexes has to be chosen

Comment: Statement $A\in\{B\}$ is true if and only if $A=B$. So $A\in\{A\cup B\}$ is in general not true. It is only true in the specific case in which $A=A\cup B$.

Comment: Further the way that $\mathcal T_{\mathcal B}$ is defined is clumsy/wrong. Think of it like this: $A\in\mathcal T_{\mathcal B}$ iff $A$ can be written as an arbitrary union of sets that are elements of $\mathcal B$. Then if $\mathcal B$ is a basis it can be proved that $\mathcal T_{\mathcal B}$ is a topology.

Answer (score 3):

The notation makes no sense, since $\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ is something that depends on $I$ (and $i$ is not a free variable), whereas the conditional $B_i\in \mathcal B$ depends on $i$ (and is probably intended to be true by definition).

Perhaps what was meant was the following. Let $i$ be an index set so that $\mathcal B=\{B_i:i\in I\}$. Then define $\mathcal{T_B}=\{\bigcup_{i\in I'}B_i:I'\subseteq I\}$, i.e. the set of all possible unions of subsets of $\mathcal B$.

In that case it would be true that $B_i\in \mathcal{T_B}$, by considering $I'=\{i\}$.

Answer (score 2):

I will be answering this question based on the set notation standards that I have been taught. $A\cup B$ is a set. Thus, $\{A\cup B\}$ is a set of a set. It is a set with only one element, $A\cup B$. For $A$ to be an element of $\{A\cup B\}$, $A$ must equal $A\cup B$. Thus, $B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score -2):

No it's not true. If S = $\{A \cup B \},$ then $A\subseteq S$.

For $A \in S, S = \{A,B\}$